# Spring Boot Gradle bootBuildImage fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, gradle

I am trying to build a docker image for my Gradle-based Spring Boot project, but I got the below error. It was working before I updated my Mac's Docker Desktop application. Docker seems to be working fine, but I can no longer build Docker images with the Gradle command.

Error excerpt:

```
Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':bootBuildImage'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:147)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:145)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:133)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:333)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:320)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:313)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:299)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:143)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:227)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:218)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:140)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.docker.transport.DockerConnectionException: Connection to the Docker daemon at 'localhost' failed with error "[2] No such file or directory"; ensure the Docker daemon is running and accessible
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.docker.transport.HttpClientTransport.execute(HttpClientTransport.java:161)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.docker.transport.HttpClientTransport.execute(HttpClientTransport.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.docker.transport.HttpClientTransport.post(HttpClientTransport.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.docker.DockerApi$ImageApi.pull(DockerApi.java:183)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.build.Builder$ImageFetcher.pullImage(Builder.java:210)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.build.Builder$ImageFetcher.fetchImage(Builder.java:194)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.build.Builder.build(Builder.java:101)
    at org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootBuildImage.buildImage(BootBuildImage.java:411)
```

Comment: `Connection to the Docker daemon at 'localhost' failed with error "[2] No such file or directory"; ensure the Docker daemon is running and accessible`. It's unable to connect to the Docker daemon. Does the `docker` command work on its own?

Comment: Which version of Docker Desktop are you using?

Comment: @blacktide yes, the docker command works on its own.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson my docker version is 4.13.0 (89412).

Answer (score 1):

There's a [breaking change in Docker Desktop 4.13 on macOS](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#docker-desktop-4130):

> By default Docker will not create the /var/run/docker.sock symlink on the host and use the docker-desktop CLI context instead.

Spring Boot is [going to be updated to cope with this change](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/32897). In the meantime, you should be able to create the symlink manually. Alternatively, you could configure Spring Boot to use `$HOME/.docker/run/docker.sock`:

```
tasks.named("bootBuildImage") {
    docker {
        host = "$HOME/.docker/run/docker.sock"
    }
}
```

Comment: I used host = "unix:///Users/olu/.docker/run/docker.sock" in the bootBuildImage task but I still got the same error: "Connection to the Docker daemon at 'localhost' failed with error "[2] No such file or directory". I have navigated to the folder ".docker/run/docker.sock" on my device and I can confirm that the docker.sock file is present.